# .Net SessionID is changing on every request

Tags: asp.net, session-state, sessionid

I want to save basket data into the session, but I've found that the session is not persisting. When I debugged the session, I realized that SessionID changes between requests.

I have the following on my master page:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) { 
    base.OnInit(e); 
    Session["B2C_Session"] = true; 
}
```

Why would this happen? What causes it and what can I do to fix it? I am using .net 3.5.

Comment: You should really provide more information or code.  By default ASP.NET applications store session id's in a cookie.  If the client is refusing that cookie, then the session id won't be stored so you won't have a way to tie that client to a specific session.

Comment: in master page:
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
 {
  base.OnInit(e);
  Session["B2C_Session"] = true;
 }

Comment: Thanks to the hint from Ek0nomik, I have checked and deleted cookies of localhost.

Then after restarting the application it worked. Probably the localhost's session cookies were interfered with each other. Got this problem a while ago, but forgot the solution. 

I writing a reply to myself here in case someone needs it.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer in case someone finds this posting in the future.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default ASP.NET applications store session id's in a cookie. If the client is refusing that cookie, then the session id won't be stored so you won't have a way to tie that client to a specific session.

Ensure that the client is accepting the cookie so the session can be persisted.